# Trying to create for loop which iterates through each item in a list to find any matches in a separate list and then replace the match

Tags: python, regex, list, loops, list-comprehension

I have two lists, one which contains banned words, like so:

```
bad_words = ["Boris", "Johnson", "coronavirus", "daily", "cases", "BBC"]
```

Another which contains a news article where each line of the article has been appended to the list like so:

```
news article =  ['Boris Johnson outlined a three-tier system, based on the severity of coronavirus cases in each area.' 'The BBC will report more shortly.', 'And so on.', 'And so on.']
```

I've created a for loop which iterates over each of the banned words and searches for them in the news article. It then replaces them with an asterisk for each character of the word. It then pops this into another list called `text_bad_words_removed`. See my code below:

```
for line in news_article:
    for word in bad_words:
        if word in line:
            asterisks_to_replace_word_with = '*'*len(word)
            newline_with_asterisks = re.sub(word, asterisks_to_replace_word_with, str(line))
            text_bad_words_removed.append(newline_with_asterisks)

print(text_bad_words_removed)
```

The result, should look like this:

```
text_bad_words_removed = ['***** ******* outlined a three-tier system, based on the severity of *********** ***** in each area.' , 'The *** will report more shortly.', 'And so on', 'And so on']
```

However, it looks like this:

```
text_bad_words_removed = ['***** Johnson outlined a three-tier system, based on the severity of coronavirus cases in each area.', Boris ******* outlined a three-tier system, based on the severity of coronavirus cases in each area.' , 'Boris Johnson outlined a three-tier system, based on the severity of *********** cases in each area.', 'Boris Johnson outlined a three-tier system, based on the severity of coronavirus ***** in each area.', 'The *** will report more shortly.', 'And so on', 'And so on']
```

The problem is that if there are several bad words in the same line, it will copy the entire line to the list again if there is another bad word in the same line. As you can see above.

How do I solve this? Can I make it so that the loop replaces all the bad_words in one line and then adds that line with all of the bad words replaced to my new list?

Comment: The `re.sub` line runs on the original `line` each time, so all previous changes are discarded.

Comment: Please de-politicise or at least politico-neutralise your questions, by either removing obvious biased use of political names, or using a relatively balanced mixture of names. E.g. you could add a headline from The Guardian "Jeremy Corbyn and Stanley Johnson apologise for Covid breaches" or from The Express and Star "Jeremy Corbyn ‘broke coronavirus rule of six at dinner party’"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this all with a single regex and single loop.
Something like this.

```
>>> import re
>>> news_articles =  ['Boris Johnson outlined a three-tier system, based on the severity of coronavirus cases in each area.', 'The BBC will report more shortly.', 'And so on.', 'And so on.']
>>>
>>> bad_words = ["Boris", "Johnson", "coronavirus", "daily", "cases", "BBC"]
>>> rx = '(?i)(?:{0})'.format('|'.join(bad_words))
>>>
>>> for article in news_articles:
...     articleNew = re.sub(rx, lambda x: '*'*len(x.group()), article)
...     print( articleNew )
...
***** ******* outlined a three-tier system, based on the severity of *********** ***** in each area.
The *** will report more shortly.
And so on.
And so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compile regex with bad words beforehand and then use it in list comprehension:

```
import re


bad_words = ["Boris", "Johnson", "coronavirus", "daily", "cases", "BBC"]
news_article =  ['Boris Johnson outlined a three-tier system, based on the severity of coronavirus cases in each area.', 'The BBC will report more shortly.', 'And so on.', 'And so on.']

to_replace = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, bad_words)))
new_txt = [to_replace.sub(lambda g: '*' * len(g.group(0)), line) for line in news_article]

# pretty print to screen 
from pprint import pprint
pprint(new_txt)
```

Prints:

```
['***** ******* outlined a three-tier system, based on the severity of '
 '*********** ***** in each area.',
 'The *** will report more shortly.',
 'And so on.',
 'And so on.']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in range(len(news_article)):
    for word in bad_words:
        if word in news_article[line]:
            news_article[line] = news_article[line].replace(word, '*'*len(word))
```

Comment: where is the expected text_bad_words_removed ?